# how will the hashset add to the following situation

Tags: java

```
    public class Employee
    {
    int empId;
    String empName;
    }
```

Employee object has to be added to an hashset. 
I am implementing the equals method where  only the empName is used to compare the 2 objects. 
In one of the cases they happen to be same. 
Is it possible to have a different hash code if i override hashcode method.
what is the possibility to add both objects to hashset?

Comment: If you override `equals()`, you must also override `hashCode()` and vice versa. If it correctly done, it will not be possibly to have both in the `HashSet`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis As we know that hashset will use hashcode to place the object inside it. Now if i am using only one field empname to check whether they have same hashcode or not, and if they happen to have the same hashcode , then what will happen

Comment: Why don't you test it for yourself? And read the class' javadoc.

Comment: It only calls equals if the hashCode()s are the same. It doesn't call the default equals if you override it. so in this case if hashcode are equal will the object get added to the hashset if the empName are same for both the objects and i am using only empname to compare the 2 objects

Comment: Stop asking and try it. If hashes are the same, it tests for equals. What happens if they are?